# Puppeteer Frame Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I have multiple iframes on an opened page. Is it possible to distinguish the requests of one frame from another? As I can see, the `page.on('request')` listener doesn't have such an option.

Answer (score 0):

When listening for the [`'request'`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-request) event, you can use [`request.frame()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestframe) to determine the frame that initiated the request:

```
page.on('request', request => {
    const frame = request.frame();
    console.log(`Request Frame: ${frame.name()}`);
});
```

Comment: he ask how to listen to request that come from specific frame